What formula was used here to calculate the average search time of the binary tree?
My teacher showed me the following slide on the PowerPoint with two binary search trees and their corresponding "average search times". The PPT did not mention what formula was used to calculate it. What formula am I supposed to use to calculate it?


I think I figured it out.
The "average search time" described above is the sum of the number of comparisons needed to get to each node for all nodes divided by the total number of nodes. For example, for the first tree:
Jan: 1
Feb: 2
Mar: 2
Apr: 3
May: 3
June: 3
July: 4
Aug: 4
Sept: 4
Oct: 5
Nov: 6
Dec: 5
Sum of the comparisons: 42
42/12 = 3.5

An alternative way is to count how many items are at each level (1 = Jan at level 1, 2 = Feb, March at level 2) and so on. That also gives you a lower bound. Here if the number for each level are 1, 2, 4, 5.
